# World war 2 time travel film

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel, ghost

I am trying to identify a film:

- It's a sort of time travel / ghost film, probably made for TV
- It features an American or Canadian soldier in the UK in World War II

This is what I remember about the plot:

This person knows people at this quaint little cottage with a white gate.  He then gets to know the posh people at the big mansion house nearby and falls in love with one of the girls.  He has to leave town and when he returns (months later), the cottage is derelict.  I think that the mansion also had a fire and hadn't been lived in for about a hundred years, so he fell in love with a ghost.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 14):

Could this be *[From Time to Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/From_Time_to_Time_(film))*?

> Near the end of World War II, teen-aged Tolly (Alex Etel) goes to
> spend Christmas at his grandmother's large country estate, Green
> Knowe. Tolly's soldier father has been reported missing in action
> while his mother remains in London awaiting more information. His
> grandmother, Mrs. Oldknow (Maggie Smith), disapproved of her son's
> marriage, considering his wife a commoner. Mrs. Oldknow is financially
> strapped and faced with selling Green Knowe.
>
> On Tolly's first night at Green Knowe, he sees and hears a ghostly
> young girl and adolescent boy. Soon after, he discovers that he
> magically time travels between the present and the early 19th century
> in the old manor house. Certain people in that time period can see and
> communicate with him, while he remains invisible to others. Susan, the
> blind daughter of Lord Thomas Oldknow, is the ghostly figure that
> Tolly first saw. She can speak to Tolly both in her time and his. He
> learns that his grandmother also sees the ancestral ghosts. Susan
> leads him on an adventure that unlocks family secrets laid buried for
> generations. Exciting events include a terrible fire, a tale of stolen
> jewels, and threats of a servant being sold into a press gang.

Comment: No. Not that film unfortuntely